# Retrieving data from httprequest

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, request

I'm working on this server side asp script.It is supposed to receive a xml stream from a web app and save it in a xml file. The problem is I'm haven't been able to read this stream. I used different methods and I can't seem to find the right one. One other thing is for testing I'm using rest console add on for chrome and it seems to work with no problems but when my client sends the stream I'm unable to read it and they receive a code 500 error.

at first I tried reading the stream in binary mode then converting it

```
function readContent()
  dim a,b
  a=Request.TotalBytes
  b=Request.BinaryRead(a)
  writeInLogFile(" ")
  writeInLogFile(Time & Request.ServerVariables("ALL_RAW"))
  writeInLogFile(Time & " Data read in binary mode with a size of " & a)
  readContent = URLDecode(BytesToStr(b))
  writeInLogFile(Time & " the length of the converted string is : "& len(readContent))
end function
```

but here's what I keep getting on my log file

```
17:12:10Content-Length: 8416
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Authorization: Basic 
Host: 
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/2.0.2

17:12:10 Data read in binary mode with a size of 8416

17:12:10 Converting binary to string
```

and then it crashes when I try to write the converted string

then I switched to request.form

```
function readContent()
  'writeInLogFile(Time & " " & URLDecode(Request.Form))
  writeInLogFile(Time & Request.ServerVariables("ALL_RAW"))
  readContent = URLDecode(Request.Form)
  writeInLogFile(Time & " the length of the converted string is : "& len(readContent))
end function
```

but yet again when testing via rest console all is working and when actually receiving the stream from my client it just crashes.

Anyone faced a similar problem, or has an idea to how can I solve this thing

thanks in advance

update :

here is the decoding function

```
FUNCTION URLDecode(str)
  '// This function:
  '// - decodes any utf-8 encoded characters into unicode characters eg. (%C3%A5 = å)
  '// - replaces any plus sign separators with a space character
  '//
  '// IMPORTANT:
  '// Your webpage must use the UTF-8 character set. Easiest method is to use this META tag:
  '// <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  '//
  Dim objScript
  Set objScript = Server.CreateObject("ScriptControl")
  objScript.Language = "JavaScript"
  URLDecode = objScript.Eval("decodeURIComponent(""" & str & """.replace(/\+/g,"" ""))")
  Set objScript = NOTHING
  'writeInLogFile(Time & " the length of the converted string is : "& len(URLDecode))
END FUNCTION
```

Comment: You are missing relevant code, what does the source for these two functions look like? `URLDecode(BytesToStr(b))`. But looking at what you are trying to do I'd say the problem is in `URLDecode()` function.

Comment: No there is no error in the URLDecode() function like I said when testing locally (Rest console) everything runs smoothly and the function is working perfectly.

Comment: Guess there's no problem then, you obviously know what your doing. Good luck.

Comment: That's the problem this thing still does not work when my client sends a stream and they still get a code 500 server error.

Comment: What is the `500 Internal Server Error`, does it have a description and point to the offending line?

Comment: Nope not a single hint.

Comment: Well I guess I have to try and rewrite the script in another language because I tried everything using VB but no clue.

Comment: In that case you need to enable detailed error messages in IIS (depending on the IIS version) so you can get more feedback on the cause of your issue. I'm not sure how testing it from REST Console is really going to help, the client could be encoding the stream they send incorrectly which could then be causing problems once it reaches the service.

Comment: I don't see why you need to use that `URLDecode()` function either, if you sending it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then `Request.Form("yourparameter")` will already be decoded??

Comment: Also are you positive that your client is sending the data `UTF-8` encoded? These are all points you need to consider, switching from using `Request.BinaryRead()` to `Request.Form` will not make a blind bit of difference if the encoding is wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding that client said would be sent was not the same as actually sent by the stream.

Request.Form is the answer.